# Simple c++ input program

Tags: c++

I tried making a very small a basic program to try and use input that isn't single numbers or letters. I entered this code and it doesn't work. It launches and works but when you enter in the input it stops the program without using the if and else if's. Why doesn't this work?

```
int main()
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    char input[256];

    cout << "Is Life Good?\n";
    cin >> input;

    if (input == "yes") {
    }
    else if (input == "Yes") {
        cout << "Good\n";
    }
    else if (input == "YES") {
        cout << "Good\n";
    }
    else if (input == "no") {
        cout << "Change something\n";
    }
    else if (input == "No") {
        cout << "Change something\n";
    }
    else if (input == "NO") {
        cout << "Change something\n";
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: instead of char input[216], you can use `string input` and it should work fine. Or if you want to use characer array, use `strcmp()` for comparison, which is provided in header `string.h` or `cstring`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
input == "yes"
```

To compare, you need to use `strcmp` function. `==` operator is not comparing values but the pointers.

If you use, `std::string` the existing code will work as is. `std::string` has the operator `==` overloaded which does the comparison.

I recommend to use `std::string` over character arrays.

Comment: beat me by a couple of seconds :P

Comment: The emphasis should be on `std::string` as this makes for more readable C++.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Recommended. I remember these were one of the hello-world kind of mistakes I made in my initial programming days.

Comment: Besides using std::string, not comparing pointers, a nasty user could introduce a buffer overflow, having a real long story.

Comment: Ok thanks it worked! Just started learning C++ 9 days ago so I'm still really fresh at it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

`==` doesn't work to compare strings (it compares memory addresses in your case) either use the c function `strcmp` or use C++ `std::string`